# GCM or FCM in DELPHI 10.1

Tags: android, delphi, google-cloud-messaging, push, message

I am developing a GCM Push notification without Baas

When App is running, I can get Push message. 
But, When Exit the App, no working.

**I got this log:**

```
10-10 17:53:05.762: W/ActivityManager(1554): 
Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000010 pkg=com.embarcadero.app.shgsn.fcmpushtest cmp=com.embarcadero.app.shgsn.fcmpushtest/com.embarcadero.gcm.notifications.GCMIntentService (has extras) } U=0: not found
```

I added this in `AndroidManifest.template.xml`:

```
<service android:name="com.embarcadero.gcm.notifications.GMCIntentService" />
```